# Driver gpio_keys type of buttons

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, gpio

I'm confused about the driver gpio_keys.
This driver distinguishes between two types of buttons:

IRQ-only buttons and GPIO-driven buttons

Could anyone explain the difference between one and another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not read the latest [`gpio_keys`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/gpio_keys.c) code, just skimmed over it.  Yet, I believe that there is a good explanation for the separation of GPIO keys from IRQs.

A kernel has an IRQ event table, so different events can be given to known IRQs.  The list of events (callbacks, well actually pointers) is written into a PIC (a separate chip or integrated in the CPU) and when the given interrupt happen the execution context enters into the event function.  These functions need to be small so not much time is lost inside the interrupt.

But what is really important here is that (unless the CPU is instructed to temporarily ignore interrupts) the kernel will answer every interrupt.

For a responsive application you want things connected to the GPIO pins to produce an interrupt (i.e. be like an IRQ).  Yet, there may be application where you do not care about every click of the button or every change in the state of whatever is connected to the GPIO pin.  One example could be a sensor, which you want to measure every, say, half a second.  You do not want the sensor to tell the kernel when it is "pressed" you want a userspace application to poke the kernel to tell it the current state of the sensor every half a second.  It is not hard to think of a sensor that exposes an interface that looks like a button, pretty much any sensor that has only two states (e.g. dark/light with a threshold) can look like a button.